# How to test IOS in-app purchase with real card

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have developed an IOS app with in-app purchases enabled in Flutter. I have tested the in-app purchase with sandbox environment and it shows success when done. Just to be extra sure that payment works I would like to try payment with the real card or dummy cards provided by Apple. Is it possible to test it with a real card before publishing the app to app store? Or do we need to have faith in Apple that if Sandbox works, the real pay would work too after publishing? Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only complete a full IAP after the app is published in the store.